# AS3: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.events to flash.events.MouseEvent

Tags: actionscript-3, events, coercion

When I placed this **AddEventListener** I got this "**Type Coercion failed message"**

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnterFrm);
```

Located above the mouse event:

```
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnterFrm);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _clicked);
```

I can't see the relationship in-between that causes the error.

**//Clicked Function**

```
         private function _clicked(e:MouseEvent)
     {
        gameBall = sim.addCircle({x:(mouseX/30), y:(1), radius:0.25, density:5});
     }
```

**//OnEnterFrn Function**

```
     private function onEnterFrm(e:MouseEvent):void
     {          
        if (gameBall && gameBall.body.IsSleeping())
            {
                gameBall.destroy();
                gameBall = null;
            }  
    }
```

If I hit run, the simulation works but **laggy**, and the **runtime message pops up**:

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.events::Event@2a03b2e1 to flash.events.MouseEvent.
```

**Full Code:**

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import com.actionsnippet.qbox.*;  
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

[SWF(width = 600, height = 600, frameRate = 60)]  

public class LuckyHit extends MovieClip {

    public var sim:QuickBox2D;
    var winBox:QuickObject;
    var looseBox:QuickObject;
    var gameBall:QuickObject;
    var simContacts:QuickContacts;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function LuckyHit()
    {
        sim = new QuickBox2D(this);
        simContacts = sim.addContactListener();
        simContacts.addEventListener(QuickContacts.ADD, contactListener);
        //sim.createStageWalls();
        winBox = sim.addBox({x:5,y:600/30, width:300/30, height:10/30, density:0});
        looseBox = sim.addBox({x:15,y:600/30, width:300/30, height:10/30, density:0});


        //buscar fuerza de rebote.
        // make obstacles 
        for (var i:int = 0; i<(stage.stageWidth/50); i++){ 
        //End
             sim.addCircle({x:1 + i * 1.5, y:16, radius:0.1, density:0});
             sim.addCircle({x:2 + i * 1.5, y:15, radius:0.1, density:0});

        //Mid End

              sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:14, radius:0.1, density:0});
              sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:13, radius:0.1, density:0});
              sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:12, radius:0.1, density:0});
              sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:11, radius:0.1, density:0});
              sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:10, radius:0.1, density:0});


        //Middle Start
             sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 1.5, y:09, radius:0.1, density:0});
             sim.addCircle({x:1 + i * 1.5, y:08, radius:0.1, density:0});
             sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 1.5, y:07, radius:0.1, density:0});
             sim.addCircle({x:1 + i * 1.5, y:06, radius:0.1, density:0});

        }
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnterFrm);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _clicked);
        sim.start();



    }

    /**
     * ..
     * @param e MouseEvent.CLICK
     */
     private function _clicked(e:MouseEvent)
     {
        gameBall = sim.addCircle({x:(mouseX/30), y:(1), radius:0.25, density:5});
     }

     private function onEnterFrm(e:MouseEvent):void
     {          
        if (gameBall && gameBall.body.IsSleeping())
            {
                gameBall.destroy();
                gameBall = null;
            }  
    }

    private function contactListener(e:Event)
    {
        if (simContacts.isCurrentContact(winBox,gameBall))
        {
            // Won.
            trace ('You won!');
        }
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your onEnterFrm function is looking to receive an Event, Not a MouseEvent.

change

```
private function onEnterFrm(e:MouseEvent):void
```

to

```
private function onEnterFrm(e:Event):void
```

Currently, your onEnterFrm is getting an event where it wants a MouseEvent.

Answer (score 1):

Event (Event.ENTER_FRAME) is not a subtype of MouseEvent. Hence the conversion error. Change your parameter type: `onEnterFrm(e:Event)`.